# How make Ruby on Rails app available in .onion?

Tags: configuration, onion-routing, website

I have dedicated web server working by Rybu on Rails. But I don't know how to make it work in **.onion**  link.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Tor to connect to the port your RoR application is listening on. Say this is port `8080` and you want to expose the hidden service on port `80`. Then configure it like this:

```
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080
```

See https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-onion-service